# Flutter app is throwing an error in editable_text

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am new to flutter. This error is not going away and I do not know what it means or how I can fix it. Can someone please help me out?Sometimes the app works but first the error tab comes up on the screen.
Also, the image chosen isn't dynamic i.e. after it selects the image, it throws an error and doesn't update it. This is my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  File _imageFile;
  Future getImage (bool isCamera) async{
    File image;
    if(isCamera){
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    }
    else {
      image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    }
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = image;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
          centerTitle:true,
          title:Text(
            'Profile',
          ),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Change Password'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Settings'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Column(children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Center(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: _imageFile == null ? AssetImage('images/profilepic.jpg') : Image.file(_imageFile),
              radius: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children:<Widget>[
            Text('UserName',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  fontFamily: ' MuseoModerno',
                )),
          ]),
          SizedBox(height: 40.0),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Camera'),
            onPressed:() {
              getImage(true);
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Gallery'),
            onPressed:() {
              getImage(false);
            },
          ),
        ]
        )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please for taking screenshot run `flutter screenshot` command

Comment: My emulator on android studio isn't working for some reason so I had to do this.

Comment: try run `flutter clean` command and build your project again

Comment: for taking screenshot just go to project directory - open a cmd and run `flutter screenshot` it's not depending to the android studio and emulator, this command take a screenshot from your real device

Comment: I ran flutter clean . It threw an error saying  No pubspec.yaml file found.But my pubspec is present

Comment: that means your `pubspec.yaml` file was gone, I think you project files damaged, try to create a new project and transport your codes to the new project

Comment: I got flutter clean to work. It's working now. Thank You